# From email addresses with 4 character domain names or non-normal domains

Tags: email

I am attempting to add a From email address with a .club domain. Civi is stating, "Please follow the proper format for From Email Address" when I try to save the email address. I looked for the error in all of my civicrm plug files and found one line in CRM\Admin\Form\Options.php that has text below. I thought perhaps the "3" was the length of the domain name having to be 3. I changed to 4 and still the same error. Has any one had experience in Civi with "non-normal" domains other than the usual suspects (e.g., .org, .com, etc.)?

```
  $formName = explode('"', $fields['label']);
  if (empty($formName[1]) || count($formName) != 3) {
    $errors['label'] = ts('Please follow the proper format for From Email Address');
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention -- using Civi 4.6.11 on WordPress platform

Comment: This may be ignored. It has been resolved.

Comment: For issues with "special characters" in domain names (eg `افغانستا.icom.museum`), see also [CRM-15975](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15975) and [CRM-16313](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16313). Since you asked re "non-normal" domains :)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this error is that the email was entered in the format `myname@example.org` rather than a name and email in the format `My Name <myname@example.org>`.

While the field label at `civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1` says **From Email Address**, the field actually requires you to enter a **sender name** *and* **email address**.

The field help says,

> Include double-quotes (") around the name and angle-brackets (< >) around the email address. 
>   EXAMPLE: "Client Services"

Comment: Thanks much! It was a formatting issue. The .club domain has caused issues with some providers, so I just presumed it was one of the newer 4-letter domains causing an issue, but it was that. I'm set now